# Wordpress add new Menu in the admin

Tags: wordpress

How could I add new menu after Post : media : Links : comments : `<My Menu>`???

I don't want to add in the settings section instead after the link "Dashboard"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

```
add_menu_page('Page title', 'Top-level menu title', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-handle', 'my_magic_function');
```

to add sub menu  [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

```
add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-handle', 'Page title', 'Sub-menu title', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle', 'my_magic_function');
```